# Three-Way Data Binding without Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, deployd

I am looking to make a web app where each person can add to a list and as soon as someone adds something, everyone elses browser shows the new addition.

I believe this is called 3-way data binding (I'm new to Ang). From what I can see, this can be achieved with Firebase. Is there some form of open source solution I can use that would do the same thing and is beginner friendly. I know the hacker plan on Firebase gives me 50 connections but I'm going to need more than that.

I've had a look at Deployd and Loopback.. But I'm not sure whether this would do what I want it to do.

Any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: You can do that in about 3 lines of Firebase code. I can't imagine what would be more beginner-friendly. Also, that's 50 **concurrents**, which is quite a bit more than 50 connections (around 70k visitors a month to a typical site) and plenty to get you running.

Comment: @Kato I'm almost guaranteed to have a boost of visitors in the first 2 weeks or so that will be mean at like 2,000 to it in one day. I can't have people not being able to connect because of the hard limit. And I don't have the funds to be paying $50+ a month. I don't think the 50 concurrnts (correct me if i'm wrong) can support 2,000/day. 50 concurrents means 50 people on the site at any one time yes?

Answer (score 0):

**Node backend option:**
I haven't tried this yet myself, but Meteor offers 3 way binding and the documentation looks good:
http://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/angular1/3-way-data-binding

As long as you're using node for the backend, I imagine that you could include the Meteor library even if you're not building a full "Meteor app."

**Django backend option:**
Described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24868721/706768

Comment: This may theoretically answer the question, but it would be best to include the essential parts of the answer here for future users, and provide the link for reference. [Link-dominated answers](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231) can become invalid through [link rot](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).